# text classification, rnn package R

Tags: r, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to use the rnn package of R for some short of classification. My input is text and the classes are two, let's say "1" or "2". I read the documentation of the package, was able to execute the example, there seems to be some kind of an issue with text. I converted each text string to a binary and stored in a matrix. Data and code is example:

```
text.variable.preference = c("i like orange", "i like apple", "i prefer melon", "i prefer deserts to fruits")

text.variable.not.preference = c("i don't like fruits", "i don't like vegetables", "i like pop music", "i don't like anything")

matrix.preference = matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 8)
for (i in 1:NROW(text.variable.preference){
matrix.1 = int2bin(utf8toint(textvariable[i]))
matrix.preference = rbind(matrix.1, matrix.preference)
}



matrix.not.preference = matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 8)

for (i in 1:NROW(text.variable.not.preference){
matrix.1 = int2bin(utf8toint(textvariable.not.preference[i]))
matrix.preference = rbind(matrix.1, matrix.preference.not.preference)
}

X = array(c(matrix.preference, matrix.not.preference), dim=c(dim(matrix.preference),2))
y = int2bin(rep(2:1,c(4,4)))

What I want is to train my rnn model in a way that the output of each text string would be either 1 or 2.

something like:

model.rnn = train(Y=y, X=X, network_type="rnn", learningrate=0.1, hidden_dimension = 10)
But there is the problem that dim(y) is not equal to dim(X). Pretty logical as the binary of string is much bigger than the binary of the "1" or "2".
```

I was wondering if there is a smart way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

When you are converting the text to int you are getting one input row for each character. Your labels should match this.

```
X = rbind(matrix.preference, matrix.not.preference)
y = int2bin(rep(1:2, times = c(nrow(matrix.preference), nrow(matrix.not.preference))))
model.rnn = trainr(Y = y, X = X, learningrate = 1, numepochs = 10, hidden_dim = 10)
```